# Is there a way to navigate from artboards to layers in Sketch from keyboard?

Tags: sketch-app, shortcuts

I'm new to Sketch and trying to learn as many keyboard shortcuts as possible. I know that you can use <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to navigate up and down through layers OR artboards but I can't see a way to move from a selected artboard into it's inner layers via the keyboard. Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Answer (score 2):

When you have the desired artboard selected, hit the <kbd>return</kbd>/<kbd>enter</kbd> key to activate Edit Mode and get into that artboard's layers. From here you can <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to navigate as you would on the artboard level.

It might also be of value to know that <kbd>Esc</kbd> will navigate back to the parent layer/artboard level.

***Here are a couple of great resources for keyboard shortcuts in Sketch:***

[Sketch Shortcuts - A list of Keyboard Shortcuts for Sketch App](http://sketchshortcuts.com/)

[Keyboard Shortcuts - Sketch Keyboard Shortcuts and Tricks](http://v1.designcode.io/sketch-keyboard)

Comment: PERFECT! I knew it had to be something simple. Thanks!